# Spring Batch & Integration Flat File Generation Pattern

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have a use case where we receive data in flat files which we load into an Oracle DB using Spring Batch. Post data load in Oracle, we have to distribute the data in form of flat files to several consumers. The data selection criteria depends on some pre-decided values in some fields of the data.

We have a design in place which generates a list which contains objects that can be passed to a Spring Batch job as job parameter to generate the flat files needed to be sent to the data consumers.

Using a Splitter component, I can put the individual objects into a channel and plug a JobLaunchingGateway to launch a batch job to generate the flat file.

Need help on how I can launch multiple batch jobs in parallel using JobLaunchingGateway so that I can generate files in parallel.

A setup is already in place to FTP the files to consumers. We do not need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ExecutorChannel` with a task executor before the `JobLaunchingGateway`.